# To fetch records from sqlite table between a range of dates

Tags: android, sqlite

In my application i am trying to fetch records from a sqlite table with respect to a range of dates selected from the date picker. The records in the table are as follows :

[image]

The query formed is as given below :

```
select * from Order_Master where Order_Date >= '12-04-2015' and Order_Date <= '11-03-2016' And WSS_Code = '1014332'
```

This query does not return any value which is not the desired result as the dates are in the selected range.

What could possibly be wrong here ? Am i missing something?

Kindly guide me through this. Thanking you in Advance !

Comment: both date format are different the one you are using in db and in query

Comment: if the type of Order_date is Date in table definition, than you should use Java.sql.Date class

Comment: Use the date and  time , you will get what you are looking for

Comment: @Madhur No No..Both the date formats are dd-MM-yyyy

Comment: @ankitaggarwal the datatype is DateTime

Comment: @Sree i tried with `select * from Order_Master where Order_Date >= '12-04-2015 00:00:00' and Order_Date <= '11-03-2016 00:00:00' And WSS_Code = '1014332' ` but still no results returned

Comment: i wounder how you set DateTime datatype in Sqlite

Answer (score 1):

Your date format cannot be used for comparisons, because strings are compared lexicographically, i.e., with the first characters compared first.
In this query, you are searching for dates with a month that is at least `12` and, at the same, no larger than `11`.

SQLite has no separate data type for dates.
To store dates in a database, you have to choose one of the existing data types (number or text).
When using SQLite's built-in date functions, you must use one of the [formats supported by them](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#datetime).

Answer (score 0):

Try this , hope it helps

Change your **datatype to text**

```
SELECT * FROM Order_Master WHERE Order_Date BETWEEN '12-04-2015' AND '11-03-2016' AND WSS_Code = '1014332';
```

As well as your query will also work.

Comment: I have tried this on myside and its working properly.